# iframe automatically scrolls to bottom - how to initialize it scrolled to top?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, razor

I have an UI accordion that contains various Iframes. The first Iframe is fine and doesn't need any changes, but when I open the second accordion header, the Iframe contained inside initializes scrolled to the bottom of the page. I would like to be scrolled to the top, but I'm not sure how to get there. This is being done in Razor so don't mind the @ syntax you see.

```
<div id="reports-accordion">
    <h1>Trend Report</h1>
    <div id="powerbireport">
        <iframe src="https://app.powerbi.com/view?##########" frameborder="0" allowFullScreen="true"></iframe>
    </div>
    <h1>Density Estimations</h1>
    <div>
        <p>
            James' Content
        </p>
        <button type="button" id="graphDwnld">Download Graph JPEG</button>
        @if (state == "AR")
         {
            <div>
                <iframe src="~/Content/DataVizByState/AR_Analysis_2018.pdf#zoom=100"></iframe>
            </div>
         }
         <!--Conditional continues-->
     </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#reports-accordion {
    margin-top: 30px;
    background-color: white;
}

#reports-accordion h1{
    font-size: larger;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#reports-accordion .ui-accordion-header.ui-state-default {
    background: rgb(82, 151, 95);
    color: white;
}

#reports-accordion .ui-state-default .ui-icon {
    background-image: url(../Content/img/ui-icons_ffffff_256x240.png);
}

#reports-accordion .ui-state-hover .ui-icon,
#reports-accordion .ui-state-active .ui-icon {
    background-image: url(../Content/img/ui-icons_050505_256x240.png);
}

#reports-accordion .ui-accordion-header.ui-state-hover, 
#reports-accordion .ui-accordion-header.ui-state-active{
    color: black;
}
iframe {
width: 100%;
height: 70vh;
display: block;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#reports-accordion").accordion({
        collapsible: true,
        active: false,
        heightStyle: "content"
    });
});
```

**UI Library**

`<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.4.js"></script>`

Comment: Did you try to put  id="powerbireport" to the div surrounding second iframe?

Comment: @LazarNikolic It's possible I'm misunderstanding your question but the first div that contains the PowerBI report goes under the first header, so it is the first option in the accordion. The second div contains a PDF and is the second option in the accordion. `id="powerbireport"` doesn't actually have any special styles applied that would make it differ from the other div (which is why it's not in the CSS I gave).

Comment: I don't see any issues based on what you have provided. Can you post the code you are using to make the accordion work or the accordion library you are using?

Comment: @Robert updated post. It probably just has something to do with the PDF reader plugin that gets automatically added to Iframes.